# How to set focus on control within TabControl when tab changes?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with three tabs.

First tab has several controls.
Second tab has only one control.
And the last tab has several controls.

How do I set the focus to a control within a tab when the tab page changes?

Code such as the following did not work for me:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_Selected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selected
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        TextBox2.Text = "Here"
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sergio you should consider accepting answers on your questions. This will help future readers and will also help you a little in rep.

Answer (score 1):

*I think* this may be what you are after:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage1 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "On tab 1"
        TextBox1.Focus()
    ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedTab Is TabPage2 Then
        TextBox2.Text = "On tab 2"
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the use of `SelectedIndexChanged`. I've also changed the `If` slightly to check which tab has been selected.

I have tested this with multiple tabs and controls. It works well.

If you want to set the focus of the control *and* set the position of the cursor at the end of the text in the control, you could use:

```
TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergio, you can set the control tab index in their **propieties**:

[image: Tab Index]